# Restarting the SharePoint timer service - What? How? Why?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, timer-jobs

As we all know, every so often you have 100's workflow running fine until when one of them remains in `Process` but does never continue to finilise its process. Why is that?

Some research points to the `Timer Job Service`.
But what is it exactly, how does it work?

I personally do not have much information / knowledge about it.
Some point to `reseting or restarting the Timer Service` will solve the problem.

1. Hmmm how do I do it?
2. Most importantly, will I cause more issues by doing this?
3. Am i certain to believe that it will not have an impact on any 1000's of running workflows?
4. Can I be sure that it will not stop or break other workflow instances or delete relevant information or whatever else...

Maybe somebody can provide the information and knowhow to this :)

- SharePoint 2016 OnPrem

Answer (score 0):

1. Hmmm how do I do it? - The sharepoint timer service can be restarted from windows services, services.msc
2. Most importantly, will I cause more issues by doing this? - no, the timer service runs SharePoint Timer Jobs, you will not "delete" a queue of jobs by restarting the service.  You can view all the timer jobs from central admin.
3. Am I certain to believe that it will not have an impact on any 1000's of running workflows?  From my experience no.  If the timer service is stuck, restarting it will not affect any job that has yet to run.  It will not kill you running workflows.
4. Can I be sure that it will not stop or break other workflow instances or delete relevant information or whatever else...  The best you are gonna get for SharePoint is that it shouldn't break.  But SharePoint is SharePoint.  It won't break other workflows that are in process.  And the timer service has nothing to do with saving data to the database.